# Change carrier text without jailbreak

Tags: ipod-touch, plist

I was wondering if there was any relatively easy way to change the carrier text on my iPod touch 3g (running ios 4.3.3). I've tried editing the com.apple.springboard.plist and adding the SBFakeCarrier key, but it appears that has been removed as of ios 4.2.1. Is there any similar solution?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a relatively simple method that does involve jailbreak but ends up with a non-jailbroken iPod and a fake carrier setting.

- Jailbreak your iPhone (stay with me)
- Download Cydia App: 'MakeItMine' by Erika Sadun
- Change the carrier name
- Connect your iPod and create a backup on iTunes
- Restore your iPod to factory settings
- Restore your backup

Your iPod touch should now display your fake carrier *and* be non-jailbroken.

Comment: Well, unfortunately it appears that MakeItMine no longer works since it apparently relied on SBFakeCarrier as well. I went ahead and tried Fake Operator and that worked pretty well. Haven't tried un-jailbreaking yet to see if the setting holds, but maybe I'll just keep it this way after all :)